# Integration on the $n^{\text{th}}$ power of a general quadratic function

Tags: integration

I want to integrate the following integral $$\int(ax^2+bx+c)^ndx$$
where $a\in\mathbb{C}, b\in\mathbb{C}, c\in\mathbb{C}$ are arbitrary constants and $n\in \mathbb{N}^{+}$.

Is it possible to find a general form?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried for n=2, that is polynomial of order 4. But is there any generalization possible where n can be any positive integer?

Comment: @cpc can you elaborate a little. Here we have quadratic inside.

Comment: Are you trying to do the indefinite integral so that you can then do a definite integral? If so, then it would be much easier to do the definite integral directly (without doing the indefinite integral) using a reduction formula.

Comment: yes @Dan. I will do define integration. Can you elaborate a little how to do that?

Comment: I made a mistake.   What you can do is integrate by parts.

Comment: I'll post an answer.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get it.

Comment: Apply the reduction formula
$$\int(x^2+s^2)^ndx=I_n =\frac{x^2(x^2+s^2)}{2n+1}+\frac{2ns^2}{2n+1}I_{n-1}
$$

Comment: @AsifIkbalMondalee19s014 What are your limits of integration? For example, from $x=0$ to $x=1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [trinomial expansion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial_expansion):

$$\begin{align}
(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)^n&=\sum_{~~~~~i,j,k\\
i+j+k=n}\binom{n}{i,j,k}~\alpha^i \beta^j \gamma^{k}\\
\\
\binom{n}{i,j,k}&=\frac{n!}{i!~j!~k!}=\frac{n!}{i!~j!~(n-i-j)!}
\end{align}$$
So the integral becomes:
$$\begin{align}
\int (ax^2+bx+c)^n dx&=\sum_{~~~~~i,j,k\\
i+j+k=n}\binom{n}{i,j,k}\cdot a^ib^jc^k\int x^{2i} x^j dx\\
\\
&=\sum_{~~~~~i,j,k\\
i+j+k=n}\binom{n}{i,j,k}\cdot \frac{a^ib^jc^k}{2i+j+1}x^{2i+j+1}+C\\
\\
&=\sum_{i,j}\frac{n!}{i!~j!~(n-i-j)!}\cdot \frac{a^ib^jc^{n-i-j}}{2i+j+1}x^{2i+j+1}+C\\
\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^{n-i}\frac{n!}{i!~j!~(n-i-j)!}\cdot \frac{a^ib^jc^{n-i-j}}{2i+j+1}x^{2i+j+1}+C
\end{align}$$

Comment: Dear @MathFail, a heartfelt thank to you for your good effort. I will proceed with this. Stay blessed.

Comment: Glad it helps, thank you and bless to you~ @AsifIkbalMondalee19s014